# Displacement of widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Using Kivy, I am trying to write a simple app that shows a plot and a button. I have the following code, but the problem is that I cannot control size and position of the graph in my kv file. Thus, I have a small graph at Kivy's default position in the bottom left corner as seen below. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here but can't figure out what? I appreciate if anyone can help with this.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
# Imports
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Graph(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
        figure = plt.gcf()
        self.plot = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=figure)
        layout.add_widget(self.plot)
        self.add_widget(layout)


class Interface(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return Interface()

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    TestApp().run()
```

And the following kv set-up:

```
Interface:

<Interface>:
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10


    Button:
        text: "Open"
        size_hint_x: .15
        size_hint_y: .05
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05, 'top': .55}

    Graph:
        size_hint_x: .5
        size_hint_y: .5
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5,"y":.5}
```

**Edit:**

Changing Graph to a subclass of FloatLayout as below:

```
class Graph(FloatLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Graph, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    layout = FloatLayout()
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
    figure = plt.gcf()
    self.plot = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=figure)
    layout.add_widget(self.plot)
    self.add_widget(layout)
```

enabled changing the size of the graph (FloatLayout). However, position of the graph (FloatLayout) cannot change.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using other layouts such as GridLayout or BoxLayout?

Comment: @jonyfries yes! same story.

Answer (score 0):

The layout you create in the `__init__` of `Graph` has position `(0, 0)` and size `(100, 100)`, because these are the defaults and nothing tells it to go anywhere else. When you add `self.plot`, it also has these parameters, because the layout makes the child fill itself.

An immediate fix is to make your `Graph` subclass a layout like `BoxLayout`, in which case its child will automatically be placed to fill it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. __init__ of Graph should have size (100, 100) as you said. But in the photo you can see the size is a very small portion of the root. Also, your suggestion makes Graph fill up the whole space as you said and cover the Open button. However, I want to be able to control its size with size_hint_x and size_hint_y.

Comment: That small portion of the root is probably (100, 100). And if you want to control the Graph's size with size_hints, then set those size_hints - currently you do not do so.

Comment: I have already set the size_hints in the kv file. As you suggested, I made Graph a subclass of a Layout (FloatLayout). Now I'm able to control the size in the kv file but the position cannot change as graph is not a widget subclass anymore.

Comment: The Graph in the kv file is different to the one you make in Python. It's part of your gui, but is invisible and doesn't do anything. Also, Graph *is* a subclass of Widget, because all layouts are widgets.

Comment: Maybe I don't completely understand how this works but if the Graph in the kv file is independent, then how come it can control the size of the graph?( but not position)